# Framerate on chrome android jumps above 60fps when interacting or scrolling on page

Tags: android, google-chrome, requestanimationframe

I had some issues with the fps jumping from 60fps to 120fps causing a threejs scene to run in double time when scrolling and interacting the page. After idling for a second or two, it returns back to 60fps.

I then just did a simple scrollable test html page with a fps counter and it seems like it was still the same case.

Test example : https://www.fariskassim.com/test/fpstest2/index.html

The javascript script is barebones:

```
// FPS STATS
var stats = new Stats();
container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
container.appendChild(stats.dom);

// tick
const render = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    stats.update();
};

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

It happens on my Samsung S21, Android 13, Chrome 114.0.5735.60.
And also on another test android phone just the same.

The strange thing is that when i try to screen record the page, the FPS caps back down to 60fps.

Not sure if it was always like this but its my first time encountering the issue. How do i make `requestanimationframe` run at 60fps without any hacks?